# I need to use single quotes twice - how to escape?

Tags: php, escaping

I want to run this in php but it doesn't work because of quotes....

```
    $cmd="sudo -u postgres sh -c 'psql -c \"alter user edumate with encrypted password \'BLAH_BLAH\';\" template1 2>&1' ";
    $shellOutput = exec($cmd, $output);
```

`psql -c "alter user edumate with encrypted password 'BLAH_BLAH';" template1 2>&1` is executed ok when running as postgres user.

I tried but it doesn't work for me.

```
sudo -u postgres sh -c 'psql -c \"alter user edumate with encrypted password \'BLAH_BLAH\';\" template1 2>&1'
sudo -u postgres sh -c 'psql -c "alter user edumate with encrypted password \'BLAH_BLAH\';" template1 2>&1'
```

How can I escape $cmd so I can execute it?

## update I

```
    $subcommand="alter user edumate with encrypted password 'BLAH_BLAH';";
    $sub = escapeshellarg($subcommand);
    $cmd="sudo -u postgres sh -c 'psql -c \"".$sub."\" template1 2>&1'";
    $shellOutput = exec($cmd, $output);
    echo "<pre>Output = " . print_r($output,1) . "</pre>";
```

returns

```
Output = Array
(
)
```

## update II

Thanks to @Hawili for working code. I would like to know how to run if with sh -c 'command' which he omitted.

```
$shellOutput=`sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter user edumate with encrypted password 'BLAH_BLAH';" template1 2>&1`;
```

Comment: no need for \' when enclosning string with "

Comment: @user247245: could you elaborate or provide the exact syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use back quote ` which is used by php to execute command directly into shell

ex:

```
$output = `ls -l`;
```

in your case it can be something like this:

```
$shellOutput=`sudo -u postgres psql -c "alter user edumate with encrypted password 'BLAH_BLAH';" template1 2>&1`;
```

Comment: ? check the simple example i posted before `ls -l` is it working for you?

Comment: did you tried the full command on the shell directly?, it should be written exactly in the same syntax

Answer (score 2):

You could look into this function:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php

Comment: escapeshellarg may work well too.  so $sub = escapeshellarg($subcommand); $cmd = "sudo -u postgres sh -c $sub";

Comment: $subcommand = 'psql -c "alter user edumate with encrypted password \'BLAH_BLAH\';" template1 2>&1'; $sub = escapeshellarg($subcommand); $cmd = "sudo -u postgres sh -c $sub"; as the whole psql command is basically an argument to sh.